# Flair username not updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, flair

I changed my username about a month ago across all Stack Exchange sites. I just checked my flair today and noticed that it still has my old username.

[image: profile for Chase Florell on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

*Note: my individual flair badges appear to have the appropriate username.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary glitch caused your updated display name to not be picked up by stackexchange.com. Your flair is fixed now.